# Samsung Galaxy S3 doesn't show SMS notification

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean

I need help with a problem in a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3.

I can't receive SMS notification when a SMS is sent to my mobile phone.

Every time I have to open the application to check if there are unread messages.

Notification flag is active.

I deleted cache data and I restarted the phone pressing the button "Volume up + home + power" and I selected "wipe cache partition" in "Android system recovery", but the problem persists.

Comment: What SMS apps do you have installed? If you've installed another app with permission to receive SMS messages, it's possible that it's intercepting them before the stock app can show a notification.

Comment: Have you checked under stock messenger app settings that you haven't unchecked sms notification?

Comment: Check what SMS app you are using. Check the notification settings. If all else fails install something like Dash Clock Widget so you'll be able to see messages. Is the device rooted, or have you blocked any permissions? What if you use Hangouts for SMS just to test that?

Comment: I use the default SMS app.
I deactivated Hangouts and now it works...

Comment: @Sara19: To help future readers who find themselves with the same problem, please expand your comment above into an answer and then "accept" it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I deactivated Hangouts and now it works fine.